# Unity with two scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I think this must be a super beginner question but I have searched and could not find it. If a unity project has two scenes and when building it, both scenes get checked, which scene is going to be shown or run?

Comment: That's sad to see people are so afraid of the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html) (and it's even sadder when people does not read it when someone provided them the link in [another website](http://answers.unity3d.com)....)

Comment: Already read that doc. Didn't know the difference (or sameness) of load and show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scene which appears at the top of the `Build Settings` window will be loaded first.
It can be thought of like an array, with the scene at `[0]` being shown before the scene at `[1]`

You can re-order this list by dragging.

Comment: Thanks. What about if a script is attached to the second scene. Will the objects on this script be instantiated at the beginning? Or only when scene [1] appears?

Comment: If the answer has helped you, please mark the question as answered. 
They will only be instantiated when the scene is loaded.